# Custom importer for binary encoding

Tags: voltdb

Thanks voldDb for providing amazing in-memory capabilities, and fast view of live streaming data using stream and view.

I am trying to build my custom importer which can use to stream binary data directly to the voltdb procedures.

I have created importer.jar and formatter.jar and able to load it successfully using `./bin/voltdb create -d deployment.xml`, but when I do `telnet 0 8081`, port is not open. Below is my deployment.xml config file. Please suggest if anything is missing in config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<deployment>
  <cluster hostcount="1" kfactor="0" />
  <httpd enabled="true">
    <jsonapi enabled="true" />
  </httpd>
  <commandlog enabled="false" />
  <import>
    <configuration
        module="importer.jar"
        type="custom"
        enabled="true"
        format="formatter.jar/BinaryFormatter"
    >
      <property name="procedure">MyProcedure</property>
      <property name="port">8081</property>
    </configuration>

  </import>
</deployment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, loader is disabled until load procedure is not defined.